# Unpredictable behavior JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel, html5-canvas

I have a view that uses canvas to modify a picture. Using **Ajax**, I call to controller to insert in database information about picture when user push button

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "imagenes/uploadLookTemporal/<?php echo $url_foto_temporal;  ?>";
var path = "imagenes/uploadLookTemporal/<?php echo $url_foto_temporal;  ?>";

    window.location.replace("annadir_prenda");

    $.ajax({

        type: "post",
        url: "{{ url('/postajax') }}",
        contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        //success:  function (response) {
          //  alert(response);
          //  console.log(dataURL);
        //},


    });
```

// Controller

```
public function post(Request $request){


    // Identificamos al usuario

    $user= Auth::user();
    $userfind = User::find($user->id);

    $aleatorio = rand();
    $fototemporal = new Tablatemporal();
    $fototemporal->user = $userfind->id;
    $fototemporal->url_foto = $userfind->id.'_temporal'.'_'.$aleatorio.'.'.'png';
    $fototemporal->save();


    $file = $request;

    $fotobase64 = explode ('data:image/png;base64,',$file);
    $foto = base64_decode($fotobase64[1]);



    // Alamcenamos la foto temporal y guardamos su dirección en la base de datos temporal

    //file_put_contents('imagenes/uploadLookTemporal/'.'temporal_'.$userfind->id.'_temporal.png', $foto);

    file_put_contents('imagenes/uploadLookTemporal/'.$userfind->id.'_temporal'.'_'.$aleatorio.'.'.'png', $foto);
```

The problem is that sometimes controller doesn't work, and program continues without insert in database or push picture in file system. This behavior happens only sometimes, and I can find a logic in this.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your database operation result. For example `$fototemporal->save();` returns a boolean value. Also `file_put_contents` returns bytes that written on file system or FALSE if it fails.

With these, you gain more control about your code and operation.